# Using Metamask Injected Web3 with React

Tags: metamask

Having trouble accessing Metamask's `web3 object`.

Following the recommended guidelines for using Metamask's injected web3 object 
https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#partly_sunny-web3---ethereum-browser-environment-check

Shouldn't this avoid a possible race condition?

```
 componentDidMount() {
         window.addEventListener('load', function() {

         // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
            if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
                 // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
                 window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
             } else {
                 console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')
                 // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
                 window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
         }
         })
    }
```

Still...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put the load listener inside the `componentDidMount` listener, which almost definitely fires later than the `load` event.  Try removing the load listener, the component loading should already wait long enough.

Comment: Thanks Dan, works when we move the check to the global scope albeit only by reassigning web3 object to `let web3 = window.web` which feels like a hack... trying to follow docs as closely as possible, but this is best we can manage atm

Comment: Accessing `window.web3` works for me on the first page load, but fails on page refresh, for the same timing reason you've described.